# ExpiringMap is not working to expire the object

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-mina

I tried to use ExpringMap to auto expire the map object. This is the first time I use this jar, I know there is a Guava which is popular, but I do not need cache for that and I don't know how to use the Guava either.

And I happen to know the ExpiringMap from the mina project so I tested it below, but it didn't not work. Why is that?

I hope to have a hign-performace and easy-to-use way to remove my object from the map after several minutes. Can any body give me an example for that? Thank you!

```
    ExpiringMap<String, String> map2=new ExpiringMap<String, String>(2,1);
    ExpiringMap<String, String> map10=new ExpiringMap<String, String>( 10,1);
    ExpiringMap<String, String> map5=new ExpiringMap<String, String>(5,1);

    map2.put("1", "1");
    map5.put("1","1");
    map10.put("1", "1");

    map2.put("2", "2");
    map5.put("2","2");
    map10.put("2", "2");
    int n=0;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("----"+3*n+"seconds----");

        Set<String> set2=map2.keySet();
        System.out.println("----map2----");
        for (String key : set2) {
            System.out.println(map2.get(key));
        }

        Set<String> set5=map5.keySet();
        System.out.println("----map5----");
        for (String key : set5) {
            System.out.println(map5.get(key));
        }


        Set<String> set10=map10.keySet();
        System.out.println("----map10----");
        for (String key : set10) {
            System.out.println(map10.get(key));
        }

        Thread.sleep(3000);//sleep 3 seconds
        n++;
    }
```

The out put is obious that the object is still in the map

```
----0seconds----
----map2----
1
2
----map5----
1
2
----map10----
1
2
----3seconds----
----map2----
1
2
----map5----
1
2
----map10----
1
2
----6seconds----
----map2----
1
2
----map5----
1
2
----map10----
1
2
----9seconds----
----map2----
1
2
----map5----
1
2
----map10----
1
2
----12seconds----
----map2----
1
2
----map5----
1
2
----map10----
1
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The get is causing the reference time to be reset so the timeout is never happening.  the map2 is borderline because the time is 2 seconds and the check interval is 1 second.  so its could skew to almost 3 seconds and not  timeout before its read again I think.   try putting the sleep first and try lengthening it by 3 seconds each loop and see what happens.

The following lines need to also be added before things will start expiring:

```
map2.getExpirer().startExpiring();
map10.getExpirer().startExpiring();
map5.getExpirer().startExpiring();
```

with that the 2 second expires.  the other two maps do not because the interval between references is never long enough with current code.

Comment: no, I add the Thread.Sleep(3000)before the while loop, the same. No object is invalided.

Comment: The three seconds before the while loop would have similar effect as 3 seconds at end of while loop  in both cases you just referenced (put or the get) the items in the list and then you do the get to print things out (resetting the time).  not saying there is not problem with the class your using but suspect its still that the usage is so close to the time the 2 second one would expire that you    might not get the chance to have the class expire it. try 3.5 seconds in front and see if the 2 2nd expire class does expire.

Comment: gave it a try and found with extra time its still failing.  going to poke at it a little more and see if I can figure out whats up.

Comment: looks like you need the following lines added:
        map2.getExpirer().startExpiring();
        map10.getExpirer().startExpiring();
        map5.getExpirer().startExpiring();